# Kafka Connect Debezium with ms sql server. Key extract configuration problem

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I am working with Debezium and kafka connect.  I need to extract "listid" from the payload below and be able to assign it to the kafka message key.  Using the configs in my connector file I am unable to extract the value.  Appreciate any assistance with solving this.

```
{
    "before": null,
    "after": {
        "listid": 19,
        "billingid": "0",
        "userid": "test",
```

Connector properties

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false


value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

transforms=unwrap,extract
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.extractkey.type==org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractkey.field=listid


key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=true
```

---

Sooooo I am continuing to experiment and wanted to share a better explanation of the problem and what I have experimented with.

Following along with Robin's blog https://www.confluent.fr/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/

1- running kafka-avro consumer from the terminal

KEY

```
{"LIST_ID":10058}
```

VALUE

```
{"before":null,"after":{"test.dbo.test.Value":{"LIST_ID":10058,"billingid 
etc...
```

2- I am trying to get the key to be the value 10058

3 - This is what i have for my transform configuration

```
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
transforms=createKey,extractInt,
transforms.createKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.createKey.fields=LIST_ID
transforms.extractInt.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractInt.field=LIST_ID
```

I am using debezium connector in my pipeline against mssql server.

Comment: Soooo I did review https://www.confluent.fr/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/. when I run the

Comment: I did review https://www.confluent.fr/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/.  I modified the props to support the article configus. When running the kafka avro consumer the key now shows up {"_LIST_ID":24892}. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo (`extract` vs `extractkey`):

```
transforms=unwrap,extractkey
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.extractkey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractkey.field=listid
```

Comment: I made the adjustment but I still get {"LIST_ID":4524} for the key value verses 4525.  I appreciate your response.

Comment: Try to set `transforms.extractkey.field=LIST_ID`

Comment: Thank you Alex.  Still no luck :-(

Comment: Please show again what's exactly contained in the message key (`LIST_ID` or `_LIST_ID`)

Comment: Hi Alex,  I keep getting the key returned {"LIST_ID":1535}. I am failing to extract just the integer value 1535 :-(

Comment: How do you get messages from Kafka?

Comment: 1- running kafka-avro consumer from the terminal

KEY

{"LIST_ID":10058}
VALUE

{"before":null,"after":{"test.dbo.test.Value":{"LIST_ID":10058,"billingid 
etc...

Comment: Is it the newest message in the topic? Did it produce after changing configuration?

Comment: Hiiii so I wipe the topic clean by setting the retention policy to 0.  Once the topic is clean i begin each new test using the consumer.

Comment: By the way THANK YOU so much for helping :-)